# Why doesn't iTunes search api work with app ID?

Tags: itunes

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=1542332918
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleid=1542332918
```

I tried both, it returned nothing. this is a game in in iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Try refining your search to the specific country where the app is available:

```
curl https://itunes.apple.com/cn/lookup?id=1542332918
```